# Top level javascript imports - Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to learn redux and I've run into an error. I only have two files, an index.html file and a main.js file, there are links to the jquery and redux cdns in the html file. I've only gotten to 2.3 in the redux tutorial(http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html) and am stuck. I have

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
```

at the top of my main.js file, but when I load the application, I get an error pointing to line above saying

`SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level`

What is a 'top level import declaration'?

Here is a gist to my code if that helps. https://gist.github.com/austincarvey/6e6c8fdc2640b0f9bbfb

Comment: I am not sure there is enough information to figure this out. What browser produces this error?  Also, Redux uses ES6 sysntax which means you are transpiling.  Could you create a fiddle of this?

Answer (score 9):

The `import` directive is not recognised by web browsers. It's used at the compilation stage, to tie together different source files and third party modules into a single web bundle. If that doesn't make sense, then I highly recommended learning Babel and either Webpack or Browserify. Babel transpiles ES6 and React syntax to browser friendly ES5 code, whilst Webpack/Browserify bundle your modules.

For now however, if you just want to get on with learning Redux, you can simply remove the import statement and instead use the global variable `Redux` exposed by the redux CDN script in your gist. i.e.

```
var store = Redux.createStore(counterReducer);
```

Answer (score 3):

`import` is used when you are including a file via es6 modules in a context that supports them (Browserify/Webpack/etc, future versions of browsers).

Since you are including the Redux lib via `<script>` tag, that takes care of including `Redux` in the global scope.

In the case of your gist, if you erase line one and change the `createStore` invocation to `Redux.createStore` on 29, everything should work.